# How to select second last row from table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Table Name :- ModelParam_EMS

Primary Key :- ParameterID

No of Rows :- 500

want to select `499`th row from table only.

`Note :- No. of rows can be less or more but not fixed.`

Create Table :-

```
            CREATE TABLE `modelparam_ems` (
              `MakerModelID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
              `ParameterID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `Category` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
              `ParameterName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `ParameterAdd` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
              `ParamterType` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
              `DataTypeIndex` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
              `DefaultResolutionIndex` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
              `ParamUnit` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `ParamMaxVal` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
              `ParamMinVal` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
              `ParamVal` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
              `CreatedByID` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
              `CreatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              `ModifyById` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
              `ModifyOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              `chanelno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`ParameterID`),
              KEY `MkrMdlId` (`MakerModelID`),
              KEY `DTIndex` (`DataTypeIndex`),
              KEY `ResIndex` (`DefaultResolutionIndex`),
              KEY `CrtByID` (`CreatedByID`),
              KEY `ModfyById` (`ModifyById`),
              KEY `paramTp` (`ParamterType`),
              KEY `Categor` (`Category`),
              KEY `idx_modelparam_ems_parameterid` (`ParameterID`),
              CONSTRAINT `Category` FOREIGN KEY (`Category`) REFERENCES `category_ems` (`categoryid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
              CONSTRAINT `m2m3` FOREIGN KEY (`MakerModelID`) REFERENCES `makermodel_ems` (`MakerModelID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
              CONSTRAINT `modelparam_ems_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CreatedByID`) REFERENCES `userlogin_ems` (`UserID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
              CONSTRAINT `modelparam_ems_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ModifyById`) REFERENCES `userlogin_ems` (`UserID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10012 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you provide your CREATE TABLE ? you may want to use rownumber for this

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli, I edited above question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name DESC
LIMIT n - 1, 1
```

The query just returns the first row after n-1 row(s)

For example, if you want to get the second most expensive product (n = 2) in the products table, you just use the following query:

```
SELECT productCode, productName, buyPrice
FROM products 
ORDER BY buyPrice desc 
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Try this. Could test here and it's ok.

[Found this site helpfull](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/)

Comment: TOP is not working in Mysql

Comment: You should use LIMIT with mysql. it's the same of TOP.

Comment: No No it's fine,I want in Mysql

Comment: Yes, this is good. I prefer the verbose but more clear `LIMIT 1 OFFSET x` syntax over of the obfuscating `LIMIT x,1`.

Comment: Would SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name  -- note no "DESC"
LIMIT 1, 1 not be better as it would use the natural order of the index. Could you give times for both?

Comment: @Vérace What's the difference between your suggestion and Rafael's? I don't see any. By the way, you can format code in comments. Using `\`SELECT * FROM table_name\`` will show up as: `SELECT * FROM table_name`

Comment: Yes, but to get the "second last" column_name element, I was wondering if using the index's natural sort order (i.e. the unnecessary keyword ASC) would be any quicker for this sort of search? LIMIT n -1, 1 (DESC) or LIMIT 1, 1 (ASC) - is there any difference?

Comment: @ypercube - is what I have written above rubbish, or could it make a difference? A btree search has to start somewhere, and my understanding is that it searches in lexicographical order, so the ASC might be marginally quicker?

Comment: @Vérace but they needed the second from the **last**. So the equivalent of `ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1,1` would be `ORDER BY col ASC LIMIT f-2,1`, where `f` is the number of rows in the table (and assuming there is no WHERE clause). First, we'll have to know or find this f (how would that be done?) and second, even in a fixed-rows table, working through the index from the end (backwards) and stopping after only 2 items would be much faster than working from the start (forwards) and transcending through all of the index.

Comment: Even if you compare `ORDER BY col ASC LIMIT 1,1` and `ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1,1` (which are not equivalent), you'll find that the efficiency is almost identical (maybe slightly better for the 1st case than the 2nd. But very slightly.)

Comment: To conclude (and sorry to the rest for the long comments), MySQL has no problems (and almost identical efficiency) scanning an index backwards or forwards. Some other DBMS out there may have different efficiency though in this aspect, so your question is not rubbish at all.

Comment: @ypercube - I see my error now. I misinterpreted Rafael's answer. I confused rownum with n in his response, hence my confusion. All these *&^!££* servers to get to know!